# Shuffle array with exchangeObjectAtIndex Loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, loops

I have an array called `mainArray`. Say it contains `Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue`.

I want to reorder the `mainArray` using values from my other two arrays, `shuffleArrayIndex` and `shuffleArrayRand`.

`[mainArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:x withObjectAtIndex:randInt];`

The index value `x`, will come from the `shuffleArrayIndex`. Say `shuffleArrayIndex` contains `1, 3, 4, 2, 0`.

The withObjectAtIndex `randInt` will come from the `shuffleArrayRand`. Say `shuffleArrayRand` contains `2, 1, 3, 4, 1`.

So I want to create a loop that will exchange the `mainArray`'s objects 5 times (the `mainArray`'s `.count`)

So the first exchange will look like:

`[mainArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:1 withObjectAtIndex:2];`

And the Second:

`[mainArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:3 withObjectAtIndex:1];`

And the Third:

`[mainArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:4 withObjectAtIndex:3];`

So how can I create a loop that does this, that will exchange as many times as the `mainArray.count`?

So if the `mainArray` has 50 objects, and the `shuffleArrayIndex` and `shuffleArrayRand` have 50 objects, the loop will exchange the `mainArray`'s objects 50 times.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, took a while.

```
  for (int x = 0; x < beastStatusArray.count; x++) {

                    NSNumber *indexNumber = [shuffleArrayIndex objectAtIndex:x];

                    NSNumber *randNumber = [shuffleArrayRand objectAtIndex:x];

                    NSUInteger indexNumb = [indexNumber integerValue];
                    NSUInteger indexRand = [randNumber integerValue];

                    [mainArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexNumb withObjectAtIndex:indexRand];
                }
```